# How to use Ocaml type with a function mapping?

Tags: ocaml

I have a type defined as `type abc = bool->int;;` which sort of explains a simple mapping from `bool` to `int`. My question is, how do I use this `type abc`?

Like for example if I had

`type Color = Red|Green|Blue|Dark of Color|Light of Color;;`

Then I could use something like `Dark Red;;` having `type Color`.
But now I can't seem to use this new `type abc`.

Comment: This is a weird question. Normally you start with a problem and write code to solve that problem. You don't write random code and then go "well, how do I use this now?".

Comment: I am using a similar mapping in my function, but i cannot disclose that code here. And i am stuck here, i don't know how to use this type definition of a mapping. :(

Comment: The usual term for this "mapping" is "function". `bool -> int` is the type of functions that take a `bool` and return an `int`. Your `abc` is an alias (another name) of that type.

Comment: I wanted to use this type "abc" in a pattern matching case, but i don't know how i would use it. For example the pattern i need to match is 'B (b,s) -> * something of type int*' here B is a constructor and b is of type bool and s is of type abc, so now how would i use it to return an int ?

Comment: The way you use functions is you apply them to an argument. So if you have a function `s` and an argument `b`, you write `s b` to get the result. (Jeffrey Scofield's answer below contains an example of exactly this.)

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot. :) I think that's what i need for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type `abc` is a synonym for `bool -> int`, not a new type. Since it's not a new type, OCaml could already infer the type for you. The reason to declare such a type is for documentation.

So, the best answer to your question is that you would use `abc` when you want to document the type of something.

```
type abc = bool -> int

let apply (f: abc) (b: bool) : int =
    f b

let myfun : abc = fun b -> if b then 3 else 4
```

In your other example `color` is a new type. If you didn't declare it, it wouldn't exist.

(Note that type names in OCaml must begin with a lower-case letter. You can't have a type named `Color`.)

**Update**

You need to distinguish between type names (like `color` and `int`) and constructors (like `Red` and `Dark` and 412). You can't pattern match on the names of types. You can pattern match on values (like `Red` or `Dark Red` or 412). Your type `abc` has no constructors. It's a synonym.

It's also true, as @melpomene points out, that there's no equality defined for function values. So you can't match against function values.

Comment: Was using that type as just an example, but thanks for pointing out that mistake :)

Comment: I just wanted to use that function for a simple case, but i couldn't find anything close to it on the web, so i ended up here. I have just started to learn Ocaml, so finding it a little difficult..:)